# Spark mechanism of launching executors

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-2.0

I know that upon spark application start the driver process starts executor processes on worker nodes. But how exactly does it do it (in low level terms of spark source code)?

What spark classes/methods implement that functionality? Can someone point me to those classes?

Answer (score -1):

Looks at these two classes: [StandaloneAppClient](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/client/StandaloneAppClient.scala#L175)
 and [StandaloneSchedulerBackend](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/cluster/StandaloneSchedulerBackend.scala#L147)

i hope it's helpful for you